# How to engrave an object that has a subsurface modifier?

Tags: modifiers

1. I create a smooth gold brick using shade smooth or subdivision surface modifier.
2. I then try to engrave on this brick ("fine gold") using the Boolean modifier process.
3. The result is the process significantly destroys the smoothness of the brick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have something like this:

[image]

If so, just add an Edge Split modifier at the bottom of the stack, so everything will look fine again:

[image]